# Getting a malformed url exception saying there is no protocol when there is one

Tags: java, url

I'm trying to create an image from a url but I keep getting this exception java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: error. However the url I'm using does have a protocol https://i.stack.imgur.com/zB9WN.jpg Can't figure out why it won't work. Cheers

```
try {
            URL url=new URL(parser.getImage());
            BufferedImage c= ImageIO.read(url);
            ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(c);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use image then URL should be of Image like below:

URL url=new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LRx6.jpg");

can you try hard coding above url in your sample and see if that works!

Comment: is your image url is correct try printing it   URL url=new URL(parser.getImage()); System.out.println(" URL is: "+ url); you will get the your answer!

Comment: Yeah it prints this one https://imgur.com/a/2XzG9iG so I guess its just the incorrect url